# How to make a UEFI bootable ISO image with grub-mkrescue?

Tags: grub2, iso, uefi

The story so far:

> I have been following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall) to produce a customized version of Ubuntu.
>   As of now, the structure of the CD is complete. I have generated an ISO with the command:

```
sudo grub-mkrescue -o live_cd.iso /path/to/cd/directory
```

The iso image boots very well in BIOS mode.
**Though, it does not boot in UEFI mode, but shows this:**

[image]

How do I make the ISO image UEFI compatible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: cross: http://askubuntu.com/questions/661808/how-to-make-a-uefi-compatble-iso-with-grub-mkrescue

Answer (score 1):

For EFI boot you need to form a specific structure of the image's filesystem, not just bootsector (since it's unused), so have a look at Ubuntu's live-helper scripts (my guess) or examine [mki-copy-efiboot](http://git.altlinux.org/people/mike/packages/?p=mkimage.git;a=blob;f=tools/mki-copy-efiboot;hb=HEAD) script (the part of [mkimage](http://en.altlinux.org/mkimage) which I wrote and use).

In case you just need a custom rescue image, not neccessarily an Ubuntu-based one, you might like my [ALT Linux Rescue](http://en.altlinux.org/rescue) as the technology behind it is both open and explicitly created for easy derivatives (but is mostly [documented in Russian](http://altlinux.org/m-p) which didn't stop some people) -- it's basically about grabbing [live-builder.iso](http://mirror.yandex.ru/altlinux-starterkits/permalink/altlinux-p7-builder-latest-x86_64.iso), booting it on a spare VM/host and:

```
git clone git://git.altlinux.org/people/mike/packages/mkimage-profiles.git
cd mkimage-profiles
make regular-rescue.iso
grep -B6 RESCUE_PACKAGES conf.d/regular.mk
```

It might also be helpful to read the excellent Rod's book on [EFI bootloaders](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) as well as Matthew Garrett's ISO9660/EFI [quest report](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/4957.html).

Good luck whatever route you take!

PS: grub-mkrescue is not EFI aware as of 2.00 apparently.